# Buscar registro repetido en un cursor con FOXPRO

Tags: cursor, visual-foxpro, foxpro

```
CREATE CURSOR oproductos (;
codant c(150),;
marca c(15),;
modelo c(15),;
nroserie c(50),;
codfab c(15),;
nombre c(90))

SELECT oproductos
GOTO TOP
```

ese cursor lo lleno en una grilla con datos al importar desde excel,

Lo que necesito, es revisar si en el cursor oproductos  tiene el codant está repetido.

La verdad soy nuevo en esto, pero necesito que la busqueda sea de los mas eficiente posible, ojala no sea necesario usar un ciclo.
desde ya, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si aún lo requieres, te dejo el siguiente código:

```
SELECT codant, COUNT(codant) AS cuantos FROM oproductos GROUP BY codant HAVING cuantos > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Así puedes saber cuáles están repetidos y cuántas veces:

```
SELECT codant,COUNT(codant) AS cuantos from DBF('oproductos') INTO CURSOR contar GROUP BY 1
SET FILTER TO cuantos>1
```